# Conversion from DTDATE9. to DATE9

Tags: sas

In SAS Data Integration Studio I have a table with a DTDATE9. variable called `date`. When I map it in a user generated code transformation (which does not alter the variable at all) I get the error message "The informat DTDATE was not found or could not be loaded".

The same error message appears after altering the format to DATE9., and if I change the variable in an upstream transformation so that its format is DATE9., then it appears in the form *********.

How can I carry this variable over?

Much Gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `DTDATE` is only an output format. The following is the [manual's description of DTDATEw. FORMAT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295672.htm):

> The DTDATEw. format produces the same type of output that the DATEw. format produces. The difference is that the DTDATEw. format requires a datetime value.

So, your internal representation of the `date` column values are still in the `datetime.` format.

```
* Your original table could be interpered as the following.;
data dtdate;
  input date datetime20.;
  format date dtdate9.;
  datalines;
  01JAN2015:00:00:00
;

* By removing the format, you can see the internal representation.
data dtdate_raw_again;
  set dtdate;
  format date;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks D. Josefsson. It is odd to me since many of the upstream transformations worked fine, and only the user written code transformation had this issue. I got around this by other means, but this was useful info.